# TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() , difflib

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, difflib

I have a function that makes use of the value of a key in dictionary .The value is a list and i iterate over that list to compare it with my sample string.

```
for item in List1: #iterate over objects of list
    [l3,l4] = dict2[item] #this just assigns float values to l3,l4 (not needed)
    if ((distance(l1,l2,l3,l4)<200)and(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, str1, item).ratio()>0.7)):  #error here , 
        str2 = item
```

`distance` is a function that returns a float value on input of 4 float values l1,l2,l3,l4. that isn't a problem . The problem is with `difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, str1, item).ratio()`.

Here's the error:

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-441e1aa01c23> in <module>()
----> 1 BLR_data_test['modified_buildings'] = BLR_data_test['extracted_building'].apply(modify_building)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2021             values = lib.map_infer(values, lib.Timestamp)
   2022 
-> 2023         mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2024         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
   2025             from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\lib.pyd in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:44780)()

<ipython-input-26-f11f38a90e26> in modify_building(str1)
      5     for item in List1:
      6         [l3,l4] = dict2[item]
----> 7         if ((distance(l1,l2,l3,l4)<200)and(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, str1, item).ratio()>0.7)):
      8             str2 = item
      9             break

C:\Anaconda\lib\difflib.pyc in ratio(self)
    657 
    658         matches = reduce(lambda sum, triple: sum + triple[-1],
--> 659                          self.get_matching_blocks(), 0)
    660         return _calculate_ratio(matches, len(self.a) + len(self.b))
    661 

C:\Anaconda\lib\difflib.pyc in get_matching_blocks(self)
    479         if self.matching_blocks is not None:
    480             return self.matching_blocks
--> 481         la, lb = len(self.a), len(self.b)
    482 
    483         # This is most naturally expressed as a recursive algorithm, but

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Str1 is a string , and i compare it with `item`. Please note that `item` is a list of strings. 
As per the docs , difflib arguments need to be hashable and `item` doesnt have a unique hash value. How could i possibly avoid this??

Comment: Can you show a complete trace-back?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the `SequenceMatcher` to do? Matching a String and a Float is not a well-defined operation; even worse, sequence matching a float to anything is an error as a float is not a sequence (which is what the traceback tells you). Do you want to sequence-match the textual representation of the float?

Comment: No , both are strings . i'm not matching a float

Comment: Are you arguing that the traceback given by the interpreter is wrong? When the python interpreter tells you that one of your items is of type `float`, you better believe it. Just add `print type(str1), type(item)` before the `if` statement to see for yourself. You should always believe what the interpreter tells you.

Comment: here it is <type 'module'><type 'str'> . And i'm not arguing , it would be better if u were more polite . I know what i'm doing.

Comment: "I know what I'm doing" - Sorry, but you obviously don't. The traceback says one of your items is a float and you claim both are strings. And you seem to have changed your original code because now your `str1` is a module type instead! This means you have an error in an assignment to `str1`, check the places where you set this variable and if neccessary include the relevant pieces of code here.

Comment: and how do i deal with type module(objects)? my data consists of strings and sometimes numbers as a part of it..

Comment: The `module` type is the class used for an imported python module; e.g. if you `import xml` then `type(xml)` is the module type. Which means that you assign a module to `str1` somewhere. As I said in the previous comment, you would need to check all assignments to `str1`. And we can't help you debug this unless you include this in your question. The chat room you linked in your comment to the answer here doesn't show the relevant code either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would casting your item to a string still do what you want?

```
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, str1, str(item)).ratio()
```

Because it solves the TypeError but I am not quite sure of what you're doing here and if it alters the behavior of your program.

Comment: well , there's a new error , TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Could you provide a minimalistic piece of code that reproduces the error?

Comment: If I don't know what's in the variables it's going to be hard to reproduce the error. I've tried to fill the dictionaries with something coherent with your comments and it worked fine: dict1 = {'b':["c"]} // dict2 = {'a':[1,2], 'c':[3,4]} // dict3 = {'a':"b"}